# Could not resolve type name: Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel, Glass.Mapper.Sc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper, sitecore7.1

I am trying to use Glass Mapper in my MVC - v4.0.30319 project in Sitecore - 7.1.

Following are my Glass Mapper version which I have installed

- Glass Mapper version - 3.0.10.23
- Glass.Mapper.Sc version - 3.2.0.39
- Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc version - 3.2.0.34

when I installed Glass mapper Mvc from nuget it added a config file called (Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc) in App_Config -> include folder

Content of the file is as follows

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
      <settings></settings>
    <pipelines>



      <mvc.getModel>
        <processor type="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel, Glass.Mapper.Sc"/>
      </mvc.getModel>

    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Now when I run my website, it gives me below error (when running the pipeline mentioned in the above config)

> Could not resolve type name:
>   Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel, Glass.Mapper.Sc (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[]
>   parameters, Boolean assert))

but the reference is already there?

Am I missing any steps? Could someone please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The developer of Glass Mapper has recently moved some classes to a separate MVC assembly and did not change the config file. The class which could not be loaded is now in the `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc` assembly, so your config should look like this:

```xml
<mvc.getModel>
    <processor type="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel, Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc"/>
</mvc.getModel>
```