# Type has not been loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper

Following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299806/could-not-resolve-type-name-glass-mapper-sc-pipelines-response-getmodel-glass),
I have installed Glass.mapper.sc.Mvc in my MVC project and followed following steps

Created a class called "Home"

```
 [SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]
    public class Home : IPageBase
    {
      public virtual string PageTitle
       {
        get;
        set;
       }
    }
```

Created a Homecontroller

```
public HomeController()
        {
            context = new SitecoreContext();
        }           

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ISitecoreContext context = new SitecoreContext();            
            var home = context.GetCurrentItem<Home>();            
            return View(home);                
        }
```

Created a View

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc


@using Glass.Sitecore.Mapper;
@using Project.Libraries.Sitecore.Glass.Mapper.Model;
@model Home


@Model.PageTitle
```

Then a controller rendering in sitecore assigned to placeholder

but when this code gets executed it says Home class has not been loaded

```
Type Project.Libraries.Sitecore.Glass.Mapper.Model.Home has not been loaded
```

var home = context.GetCurrentItem();    // on this line in controller

Do I need to do any additional step to make glass mapper works

I have only installed Glass.Mapper.Src and Glass.Mapper.Src.Mvc in my project and then created above code to work.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to install the main Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor project found here http://www.nuget.org/packages/Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor

The MVC DLL extends the main project to offer version specific support for MVC